# Python Pandas get part of dataframe based on a mask

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
      TTL1     TTL2      TTL3       TTL4
0     val1     val2      val3       val4
1     val1     val2      val3       val4
2     val1     val2      val3       val4
3     val1     val2      val3       val4
```

and a mask that looks like this:

```
[[ 0 0 0 0 ]
 [ 0 0 1 0 ]
 [ 0 1 0 0 ]
 [ 0 0 0 0 ]]
```

I want to cut the main df, by the values of the mask: if there is 1 in a row, get the row.
so the output should be another dataframe that looks like this:

```
      TTL1     TTL2      TTL3       TTL4
1     val1     val2      val3       val4
2     val1     val2      val3       val4
```

I tried this line but it doesn't work:

```
df.loc[mask.any(axis=1)]
```

any ideas please?

thank you

Comment: I think your code sholud work. what is error?

Comment: That line should work.  Can you share what didn't work about it?

Comment: Make sure those are actually integers and not string representation of `int`. If that isn't the case, try type-casting them as `int/bool` types and then perform the subsetting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can omit `loc`, only is necessary same dimensions of `array` and `df`:

```
print (mask.shape)
(4, 4)
print (df.shape)
(4, 4)

print (df[mask.any(axis=1)])
  TTL1  TTL2  TTL3  TTL4
1  val1  val2  val3  val4
2  val1  val2  val3  val4
```

Same as:

```
print (df[mask.any(1)])
  TTL1  TTL2  TTL3  TTL4
1  val1  val2  val3  val4
2  val1  val2  val3  val4
```

Another possible problem from [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41607709/python-pandas-get-part-of-dataframe-based-on-a-mask/41607755#comment70417330_41607709) - `string` values instead `int`:

```
mask = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0 ],
 [ 0, 0, 1, 0 ],
 [ 0, 1, 0, 0 ],
 [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ]]).astype(str)

mask = mask.astype(bool)
print (df[mask.any(1)])
   TTL1  TTL2  TTL3  TTL4
1  val1  val2  val3  val4
2  val1  val2  val3  val4
```

EDIT:

If string `nan` in values you can replace them:

```
mask = np.array(
[['0', 'nan', '0', '0'],
 ['0', '0', '1', '0'],
 ['0', '1', '0', '0'],
 ['0', '0', '0', 'nan']])

mask[mask == 'nan'] = 0
mask = mask.astype(bool)
print (mask)
[[False False False False]
 [False False  True False]
 [False  True False False]
 [False False False False]]
```

Or simplier:

```
mask = np.array(
[['0', 'nan', '0', '0'],
 ['0', '0', '1', '0'],
 ['0', '1', '0', '0'],
 ['0', '0', '0', 'nan']])

mask = mask == '1'
print (mask)
[[False False False False]
 [False False  True False]
 [False  True False False]
 [False False False False]]
```

Comment: the last option with the `bool` is what I want, though if I have `NaN` in my mask, it gets a `True` value instead of `False`, how can I change it?

Comment: You can use `mask[np.isnan(mask)] = 0`

Comment: works like magic. thank you! I have another related question: if I have `1` value in the mask in row number 3 for example, then I also want the two rows before and after row number 3 (rows 1-2, 4-5) to change into ones as well, how is it possible with the mask?

Comment: I think for your problem is much better use numpy as pandas and for me numpy as a bit complicated. I can do it, but this can be very long :( So i think the best is create new question with desired output, I believe you get nice answers from numpy guru people.

Comment: Goodnight no competition from me for now 

Answer (score 3):

try using `loc` with `mask.any(1)`

```
df.loc[mask.any(1)]

   TTL1  TTL2  TTL3  TTL4
1  val1  val2  val3  val4
2  val1  val2  val3  val4
```

***setup***

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'TTL1': ['val1', 'val1', 'val1', 'val1'],
     'TTL2': ['val2', 'val2', 'val2', 'val2'],
     'TTL3': ['val3', 'val3', 'val3', 'val3'],
     'TTL4': ['val4', 'val4', 'val4', 'val4']}
)

mask = np.array([
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
    ])
```